# Keycloak behind ingress with non-standard port

Tags: keycloak, nginx-ingress

I successfully installed a keycloak with the bitnami helm chart.

the ingress settings are:

```
          ingress:
            enabled: true
            hostname: "kc-test.local"
```

My ingress is listening on port `18000` (locally). If I now call

`http://kc-test.local:18000` it works, but all links contain the url without port, e.g.:

`http://kc-test.local/admin`

The setting:

```
          extraEnvVars:
            - name: KC_HOSTNAME_URL
              value: "http://kc-test.local:18000"
```

Any ideas, how to make my ingress (nginx) pass the requested port to keycloak?

**EDIT**
Following annotations on nginx ingress do not help:

```
            annotations:
              nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/server-snippet: |
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Port $server_port;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto http;
```

Comment: Make sure that the headers `X-Forwarded-Proto`, `X-Forwarded-Host` and `X-Forwarded-Port` arrive correctly to Keycloak and are not overwritten by Ingress.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe remplace or add **KEYCLOAK_FRONTEND_URL** en var.

Source docker hub documentation
https://hub.docker.com/r/jboss/keycloak/

Comment: Thanks, does not help - also according to their docs:

https://www.keycloak.org/server/all-config?q=frontend

I could not find this variable

Comment: The property `KEYCLOAK_FRONTEND_URL` does not exist anymore since the Keycloak rewrite in Quarkus

Answer (score 0):

Okay, for those who are **reading this in 2023**, and using the Keycloak **version 21 and above**.

You can achieve this by **KC_HTTP_RELATIVE_PATH** to the desired relative path, could be \auth, and **KC_PROXY** to 'passthrough'.

The **Terraform** code below might help clarify this:

Here are the **Keycloak resources**:

```
resource "kubernetes_service" "keycloak" {
  metadata {
    name = "keycloak"
    labels = {
      app = "keycloak"
    }
  }
  spec {
    selector = {
      app = "keycloak"
    }
    port {
      name        = "http"
      port        = 8080
      target_port = 8080
    }

  }
}


resource "kubernetes_deployment" "keycloak" {
  metadata {
    name = "keycloak"
    labels = {
      app = "keycloak"
    }
  }

  spec {
    replicas = 1

    selector {
      match_labels = {
        app = "keycloak"
      }
    }

    template {
      metadata {
        labels = {
          app = "keycloak"
        }
      }

      spec {
        container {
          image = "quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:21.1.1"
          name  = "keycloak"
          args  = ["start-dev"]

          env {
            name  = "KEYCLOAK_ADMIN"
            value = "admin"
          }

          env {
            name  = "KEYCLOAK_ADMIN_PASSWORD"
            value = "admin"
          }

          env {
            name  = "KC_HTTP_RELATIVE_PATH"
            value = "/keycloak"
          }


          env {
            name  = "KC_PROXY"
            value = "passthrough"
          }


          port {
            name           = "http"
            container_port = 8080
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And here is the **ingress resource**:

```
resource "kubernetes_ingress_v1" "kafka_rest_proxy_ingress" {
  metadata {
    name = "kafka-rest-proxy-ingress"
  }
  spec {
    ingress_class_name = "nginx"
    rule {
      host = "localhost"
      http {
        path {
          path = "/keycloak"
          backend {
            service {
              name = "keycloak"
              port {
                number = 8080
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
  wait_for_load_balancer = false
}
```

Note that, the **FRONTEND_URL** is legacy and is not supported in newer version of Keycloak. Read more [here](https://www.keycloak.org/migration/migrating-to-quarkus).

Comment: @tchrist other answer is deleted. This is no longer a duplicate.